# Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1) in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My Flutter app throw error

```
E/BufferItemConsumer(18358): [ImageReader-1080x1620f1m3-18358-0] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
```

often come with black screen after i click on side menu, or a simple click anywhere.
I do not know realy what piece of code to add here, too much.
I guess the problem should be memory issue. I load some data and base64 image conversions.

What you thing that kind of error should come from?
How to free-up memory in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case removing `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();` solved my issue.